# How can I transform from cv::Mat (in C++) to tf.placeholder(in C++ Boost.Python)?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, tensorflow, boost-python

I am studying about C++ BoostPython, But I have one problem about transforming Image data type.

1. Receive DepthImage from Intel Realsense camera SR300.
2. depthImage data type = cv::Mat(this is imageformat of opencv in C++)
3. I want to put this Image of cv::Mat type in the tf.placeholder of Boost.Python, C++.

How can I do that? Please...

Comment: you are using only tensorflow C++ api ? can you use C api ?

Comment: um...I use C ++ only for a while. Anything is welcome if there is a good way!

Comment: Oh and I am using Win10 64bit ! 
not Linux !

Comment: well on windows you can use the C api, and create a tensor using 
cv::Mat img;
void* object = (void*)img.ptr() ;
int64_t* dims; //set dims
TF_Tensor* tftensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_DataType::TF_FLOAT, dims, nDims, object, data_size, &deallocator, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the follow code could work, i am not sure this is the best approach, but this is how i managed to get the the tensroflow working for me.

```
void* object = (void*)resized.ptr() ;
int64_t* dims; //set dims
//C API
TF_Tensor* tftensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_DataType::TF_FLOAT, dims, nDims, object, data_size, &deallocator, 0);

//C++ API
tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({ batch_size, objectHeight, objectWidth, objectChannels }));
int data_size = objectHeight * objectWidth * objectChannels * batch_size * sizeof(float);
std::copy_n((float*)object, data_size, (input_tensor.flat<float>()).data());
```